# Can I specify names for the elements of params hash in rails project (like ':name' instead of ':id' )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

My routes.rb:

```
Temp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :categories, path: '', only: [:index] do
    resources :entries, path: '', only: [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

This results in the following routes:

```
  $ rake routes
    category_entries GET /:category_id(.:format)     entries#index
      category_entry GET /:category_id/:id(.:format) entries#show
          categories GET /                           categories#index
```

QUESTION: **Can I specify somehow the following params: :category_id, :id?**

In more detail...
I need this because want to use not IDs but names in my path, e.g.: `http://localhost:3000/cat1/ent11`.
My entries controller is:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @entries = Category.where(name: params[:category_id]).first.entries
  end

  def show
    entries = Category.where(name: params[:category_id]).first.entries
    @entry = entries.select { |e|
      e.name == params[:id]
    } .first
  end
end
```

This code will be more understandable if instead of `params[:category_id]`, `params[:id]` i could write something like: `params[:category_name]`, `params[:entry_name]`.
**How can I do this?**

UPDATE: *I want to keep my routes resourceful...*

Answer (score 1):

In your routes.rb, you can add the line

```
match ':controller/:action/:category_name/:entry_name'
```

to have a certain controller receive the params you want. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes.

Comment: So... The alternative is only non-resourceful-routes, isn't it? I want to keep my routes resourceful...

Comment: I don't see anything in the api for the resources method that allows you to change the default generated parameter names, just the default action names.